# Working with Alchemy Embedded Xml Settings

Tags: gui-extensions, a4t

I've the following XML in my Alchemy GUI extension:

```
<client>
  <Allowed_Publishing_Groups>
    <Group>Publish Ability</Group>
  </Allowed_Publishing_Groups>
  <Allowed_UnPublishing_Groups>
    <Group>Unpublish Ability</Group>
  </Allowed_UnPublishing_Groups>
  <Ignore_Rules_For_Administrators c:type="bool">false</Ignore_Rules_For_Administrators>
  <Ignore_Warnings c:type="bool">false</Ignore_Warnings>      
</client>
```

I'm wondering what's the best way to read the embedded `<group>` nodes, from within the Javascript as [the documentation](http://a4t-api.alchemywebstore.com/html/a155bb48-95ab-49c9-9b61-ebcc119dc2dd.htm) currently shows only the .net method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to add a little more data to your elements so that the default deserialization of the client settings knows what to do with them. Assuming your `<Allowed_Publishing_Groups>` and `<Allowed_UnPublishing_Groups>` are multi valued string enumerables, as of 0.7 they'll need to look something like:

```
<Allowed_Publishing_Groups array="true" c:multi="true" c:element="Group">
  <Group>Publish Ability</Group>
</Allowed_Publishing_Groups>
<Allowed_UnPublishing_Groups array="true" c:multi="true" c:element="Group">
  <Group>Unpublish Ability</Group>
</Allowed_UnPublishing_Groups>
```

There's a slight detachment from the UI form and the serialization process, `c:multi="true"` tells the UI to make it a multi valued form element (with c:element determining what the name of the child elements should be), and `array="true"` tells the serializer that this should be a multi-valued array. From here, you should see the following in your JavaScript settings object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < settings.Allowed_Publishing_Groups.length; i++) {
    var group = settings.Allowed_Publishing_Groups[i];
}
```

Note that the current 0.7 default serializer turns the client settings into an ExpandoObject (which means all values will be treated as strings) which gets returned as a JSON object (and property names will remain as is to their xml element counter parts).

A better approach would be to use a strongly typed client object, which better controls the property types returned in the JSON object.  The strongly typed client settings is described http://a4t-api.alchemywebstore.com/html/a155bb48-95ab-49c9-9b61-ebcc119dc2dd.htm#StronglyTypedClientSettings. In this case you wouldn't need the `array="true"` attribute.

```
public class MyClientSettings
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Group")]
    public List<string> Allowed_Publishing_Groups { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem("Group")]
    public List<string> Allowed_UnPublishing_Groups { get; set; }
    public bool Ignore_Rules_For_Administrators { get; set; }
    public bool Ignore_Warnings { get; set; }
}
```

And to ensure that the JavaScript `getSettings()` call will use this class to deserialize to, you'll have to update your class that extends the `AlchemyPluginBase` class.

```
public override void Configure(IPluginServiceLocator services)
{
    services.SettingsDeserialization.ClientSettingsType = typeof(MyClientSettings);
}
```

Note that this serialization just uses the standard .NET Xml Serialization, so for example if you did not like the underscores in your C# class' property names, you could use `XmlElementAttribute` with the `ElementName` property.  You should also observe that with the strongly typed client settings, the return object will have the property names as camelcased.

Hope that helps!